# Default Prolog predicate sort

Tags: prolog

If I have a simple predicate in the database, is there a way that I can request that the results be returned in a particular order (asc/desc) without having to read them all into memory and performing a sort/2 or doing a setof/3?

For instance, consider this database:

```
animal(dog).
animal(cat).
animal(elephant).
animal(bird).
animal(aardvark).
```

I would like to somehow declare animal as sorted ASC on its first term so that I can simple query it like:

```
?- animal(X).
X = aardvark ;
X = bird ;
X = cat ;
X = dog ;
X = elephant ;
No.
```

Being able to do that would be very convenient for treating my knowledge base more like a conventional database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot sort them if you dont read them.

Ofc you can write the predicates sorted or generate them sorted:

```
findall(sorted_animal(X),animal(X),Animals),
sort(Animals,SAnimals),
maplist(assertz(X),SAnimals),
compile_predicates([sorted_animal]/1).
```

or

```
findall(animal(X),animal(X),Animals),
sort(Animals, SAnimals),
retractall(animal(X)),
maplist(assertz(X),SAnimals),
compile_predicates([sorted_animal]/1).
```

but you have to declare the predicate `animal/1` as dynamic:

```
:-dynamic(animal/1).
animal(dog).
....
```

(in the code file)

I used `compile_predicates/1` to improve the speed; however, this means that you cannot use `assert/1` or `retract/1` again on that predicate so if you add/remove animals skip it.

Alternatively you can use [ordered sets](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.17%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/ordsets.html%27%29%29) and pass it as an argument

Answer (score 1):

Prolog glossed over the complex ordering issues, dictating a strict chronological model for DB access, FIFO or LIFO, with default to FIFO. That's reasonable, because such access *defines* the computation model.

So there is no standard way to change the clause retrieve order.

I think that [goal_expansion](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=goal_expansion/2)/2 could be used to introduce such feature, and I'll attempt a prototype. But I'm not sure I'll get anything usable....

**edit**

first attempt, but using slow (but simpler) retract/assert.

```
/*  File:    order_by.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: Sep  5 2012
    Purpose: sort fact
*/
:- module(order_by,
      [order_by/2
      ]).

order_by(PredicateIndicator, Argument) :-
    (   PredicateIndicator = Module:Functor/Arity
    ;   PredicateIndicator = Functor/Arity, Module = user
    ),
    length(EmptyArgs, Arity),
    P =.. [Functor|EmptyArgs],
    findall(P, retract(Module:P), L),
    predsort(by_arg(Argument), L, S),
    maplist(assert_in_module(Module), S).

assert_in_module(Module, P) :-
    assertz(Module:P).

by_arg(Argument, Delta, E1, E2) :-
    arg(Argument, E1, A1),
    arg(Argument, E2, A2),
    (   A1 @< A2
    ->  Delta = <
    ;   Delta = >
    ).
```

test file (I tested just in user module), note that :- dynamic declaration is mandatory:

```
/*  File:    order_by_test.pl
    Author:  Carlo,,,
    Created: Sep  5 2012
    Purpose:
*/
:- [order_by].
:- dynamic animal/1.

animal(dog).
animal(cat).
animal(elephant).
animal(bird).
animal(aardvark).

test :-
    order_by(animal/1, 1),
    forall(animal(X), writeln(X)).
```

test result:

```
?- test.
aardvark
bird
cat
dog
elephant
```